# Convert date to given format is not working

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert date from one format to another using formatter.
But somehow this does not see to be working.

Following is my code

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms");
String folderName = formatter.format(today); 
Date date = formatter.parse(folderName);
System.out.println("Folder date = " + date); //This prints Wed Nov 09 06:05:57 IST 2016
```

I need date to be printed in yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ms format.
That is I need it to be 2016-11-09 06:50:25.5025 and not Wed Nov 09 06:05:57 IST 2016
In folderName  it is in correct format but when I convert back to date again format changes.
Could you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: "ms" ?? try "SSS" ! See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

You did two errors:

The format (check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a complete list of formats) is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`

And you need to print the String, not the Date.

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String folderName = formatter.format(today); 
System.out.println("Folder date = " + folderName);
```

Comment: When I print it that way it works. 
But I need date object to hold that format.
Is it possible?

Comment: @Sachin Date object **has no format**. That's what formatters are for.

Comment: Date holds the value, not the format. If you need to print it you need to convert it to a string using a DateFormat as you did.

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

> now.toString(): 2016-11-09T06:50:25.502+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Generate a string. Your desired format is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, just replace the `T` in the middle with a space. The java.time classes know about ISO 8601 formats.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;
String output = now.format( f ).replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> 2016-11-09 06:50:25.502

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).